# Websocket not working with Azure app service

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, websocket, azure-web-app-service

I'am working on websocket app. I have used Fleck(C# library) for websocket server. This demo is working in my localhost but when i deploy it to Azure webapp it give error

System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress) at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP) at Fleck.SocketWrapper.Bind(EndPoint endPoint) at Fleck.WebSocketServer.Start(Action`1 config) at FleckDemo2.FleckSocket.Start()

Below is the code snippet to start websocket:

```
string ipAddress = string.Empty;
            var host = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());

            List<IWebSocketConnection> sockets = new List<IWebSocketConnection>();

            foreach (var ip in host.AddressList)
            {
                if (ip.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                {
                    ipAddress = ip.ToString();
                    break;
                }
            }
            Fleck.WebSocketServer server = new Fleck.WebSocketServer("ws://" + ipAddress + ":80");


            server.Start(socket =>
            {
                logger.Info("FleckSocket=>server.start");
                socket.OnOpen = () =>
                {
                    logger.Info("FleckSocket=>server.open");
                    sockets.Add(socket);
                };
                socket.OnClose = () =>
                {
                    logger.Info("FleckSocket=>server.close");
                    sockets.Remove(socket);
                };
                socket.OnMessage = message =>
                {
                    logger.Info("FleckSocket=>server.message and the message is : "+message);
                    sockets.ToList().ForEach(s => s.Send(" client says: " + message));
                };

            });
```

I have also enabled "websocket-> on" under general settings of web application.

Thank You

Comment: I guess it's because you're using ipadress rather than domain name. Also, you're forcing port 80, but should use wss and port 443

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio I also tried with wss & port 443 but its not working. I tried to set domain name instead of IP address, however, this library doesn't accept the domain name.

Comment: change the library because through IP address it won't work

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio Could you please share any reference if you had? Thanks

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/blog/introduction-to-websockets-on-windows-azure-web-sites/